# gSoap: Connects over Wired network but TCP error over any wireless network

Tags: c++, gsoap

I have just started using gsoap and after spending a lot of time i have successfully included it in my project and have started to use it. The problem which has been troubling me for past many days is that when i hit a service,it connects over LAN,the connection is established but when i switch over to any wireless network connection doesn't establish,I debugged into the code and found that the connection could not be established over wireless network which results in connection timeout after apt retries.I am unable to figure out why this happens i.e why connection is not established over wireless networks,can anyone guide me as i am a newbie with gSoap and network programming as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the SOAP service hit and there was no problem of wired or wireless connection.Basically what I was doing was hitting the service from windows platform(msvc compiler) which was over LAN and then i was trying to integrate the same code with clang compiler to generate a .so to run it on an Android platform. I was getting a proper response when hitting from windows but when hitting from Android I got a TCP error.I could not find any issue in the code when I posted the question and the only difference I could see was connection type of two platforms but there was an underlying issue in integration over android due to which the error was getting generated and I resolved it and now the service is getting hit on both platforms.
GSOAP works like a charm over a network irrespective of the type(wired or wireless) so do not go astray after looking at the question thinking it can be a problem,if u think you have a similar issue,I would recommend looking into other things rather than wasting your time thinking it to be an issue like I did.